# How rank a product based based on year or certain variant related keywords?

Tags: seo, google, keywords, ranking

We have an automobile product website. Earlier people used to type  i.e. "cbr 1000" when looking for bike but now lot of queries are like " abs" i.e. "cbr 1000 abs" and like " year" i.e. "cbr 1000 2019"

We are ranking well for the first query i.e.  but not for the other ones i.e. when someone types abs or year after the model name.

How can I rank well for the above queries. Currently, URL and H1 only has ?

Answer (score 1):

> We have an automobile product website. Earlier people used to type
>   i.e. "cbr 1000" when looking for bike but now lot of queries are like
>   " abs" i.e. "cbr 1000 abs" and like " year" i.e. "cbr 1000 2019"

All the items you specified are such as "cbr 1000", "cbr 1000 abs", "cbr 1000 2019" there is data. It may be useful to create a database for all of your automotive parts, structured data for each webpage representing one car part, voice search data, annotations, open search files, a search engine for your website and link all this data. All these data will enhance the visibility of your website entities.

- Create tables for each of these data with a full specification that
  describes what these abbreviations mean the most complete technical details.
- create a **[CSV file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)** for each table.
- For each CSV file, create metadata using **[Model for Tabular Data and Metadata on the Web W3C Editor's Draft 17 January 2019](http://w3c.github.io/csvw/syntax/)**.
- For each web page, create a Dataset file using [Data Catalog Vocabulary (DCAT) - Version 2](https://w3c.github.io/dxwg/dcat/).
- For each webpage representing your automotive parts, create
  structured data using the **[Google Guide for Dataset](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/dataset)**.
- Create a file **[opensearch](https://github.com/dewitt/opensearch/blob/master/opensearch-1-1-draft-6.md)** for each webpage with car parts.
- For each webpage with your spare parts, create an annotation file
  using the guide **[Web Annotation Data Model W3C Working Draft 15
  October 2015](https://w3c.github.io/web-annotation/model/wd/)**. There, link all of the above files for one web page using "oa:motivatedBy":"oa:linking" and "oa:Composite" or "oa:List". 
  Create a **[Google Custom Search](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/tutorial/introduction)** for your website.
- Register your business in Google My Business.
- Install there a list of all your spare parts for cars.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what cbr 1000 stands for and like most here we have no idea why the year is relevant, so apologies for this rather generic response.

Produce a landing page (i.e. a blog post) that discusses the keyword (must be valuable to the reader and not spam). --> Here are Google's Guidelines (read them carefully - https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769#quality_guidelines)

If you want them to end up on a landing page where you sell the product then the product page may stress the fact that it is a 2019 model. This can be achieved in various ways - examples:

1. Friendly URL's that contain the keyword: your-domain.com/products/cbr-1000-2019
2. Metadata (Description and Title containing 2019)
3. Headers and content stressing the fact it is a 2019 model

There is really no magic behind this - you just really need to advertise a 2019 product if each year a new version is released.